# How to select and move the shapes in Preview

Tags: preview

An *oval* shape has been added to an image in Preview.app by using Mebu bar command Tools → Annotate → Oval:

[image]

I have no means to *move* this *oval*: trying to do so only results in getting handles to *resize* or *re-proportion* it:

[image]

What is the way to **select** the shape so to move it? I also did not find any obvious **select** tool on the toolbar.

Comment: do not select the shape it self. Hover over it till a hand shows, now click and hold and move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I do with shapes in Preview.

I recommend not to select the shape it self.

Click anywhere next to it to deselect (not required but safer), that way you will not accidentally reshape it.

Like in your case the shape is small and the reshaping dots are large, so it becomes tricky to select the shape for moving.

[image]

Now go back and "hover" over the shape till a **hand** shows instead arrow cursor.

[image]

Click and **HOLD** (hand animates that) and move it while holding.

Comment: thx!  is it just me or is this behavior different than most any other app on mac?

Comment: I think you are right with that observation.

Comment: This behavior is not really different *per se* I'd say, meaning that for *larger* ovals you don't need to deselect it first, but can "grab" it by click-holding the shape in between the resizing dots. The reason why you need to first deselect for such small shapes is that while selected the resizing dots are visible and obscure the area that is meant to be grabbed for just moving. Preview does have slightly larger resizing dots as, e.g. Pages it seems, but depending on the shape size that might happen there as well.

Comment: is there a way to prevent hand cursor from appearing, like if i try to draw on the circle with pen tool it gets selected instead.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to show the Inspector. It will list all the shapes added in the current editing session.
2. Click on the desired shape in the Inspector. This will also select the shape.

[image]

3. Now use the arrow  keys to move the selected shape, **Up** <kbd>↑</kbd>, **Down** <kbd>↓</kbd>, **Left** <kbd>←</kbd> or **Right** <kbd>→</kbd>.
4. Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key along with the arrow key to move the shape with faster speed.
5. Alternatively, once the shape is selected (either by clicking on it or via Inspector), you can also hover the mouse pointer over it until the cursor turns into a white glove. Thereafter, you can click and drag to move the shape freely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue, or similar ones with Preview, always remember to zoom the image in. When zoomed in, it is easier to select shapes and such because the ovals become smaller as a percentage of the image.

On the subject, I wish someone would send me the OS X Preview source code so I can fix the infuriating bug where a selected object moves the tiniest bit when I'm just trying to select it, inevitably screwing up its oh so accurately located position. UGH!